# How to test for pre-trends in a DiD setting with repeated cross sectional data?

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have a dataset consisting of repated cross sections spaced out every two years (e.g, 2008, 2010, 2012...). I am running a DiD specification to identify the causal effect of treated individuals after the treatment kicks in in 2012.

To check for pre-trends, my idea was to run an event study framework in which I run the following specification:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_1 \times (D_i * 2008) + \beta_2 \times (D_i * 2010) + \beta_3 \times (D_i * 2012) + + \beta_4 \times (D_i * 2014) + ... + \epsilon_{it}
$$

I have two questions:

- In the specification above, $D_i$ is an indicator for whether an individual is treated, but I am not quite sure what value this should take when it is interacted with the lags (before 2012) and leads (after 2012). Should it be = 1 if an individual is treated after 2012? Or should it be = 1 if an individual is treated in the corresponding lag/lead period?
- My data is of repeated cross-section nature, so it does not allow me to track individuals across time since none of them overlap across periods. Is it even possible to run this design with this data?

Comment: Welcome. How are the individuals aggregated? Are you sampling individuals by county/state/region?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Hi, the unit of observation is the individual, and their states and counties are identified in the data. I’m running the DiD specification as TWFE where I control for state and year fixed effects, but the outcome, treatment and some controls are individual-level variables.

Comment: At what level is the treatment administered? Is this a state level treatment?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I consider individuals treated if they are eligible for the policy (I am working to get intent-to-treat estimates only). Individuals are eligible based on a series of demographic variables, and I assign treatment (eligibility) based on them. So the treatment is technically administered at the individual level. Does this make sense? Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: In settings with repeated cross-sections, the policy or treatment *should* be well-defined at some higher level of aggregation. In your setting, however, the policy affects different people in different years. This is okay, but by virtue of your sampling scheme you're not following the same individuals before *and* after the policy/treatment. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What would this imply?

Comment: It implies you have the wrong research design. But let's unpack that a bit. Are you looking at some demographic group, as a whole, over time?

Comment: Hi, I figured that would be an issue but wasn’t 100% sure. Thanks for the clarification. With respect to the question, my project focuses on low income individuals and the effect of a certain subsidy on their behavior. I restrict my sample to include relatively low income individuals, and those that meet certain threshold are considered eligible. There's some additional important information that perhaps is relevant, but I'll add it on another comment as I do not have enough space here.

Comment: Importantly, there’s an additional dimension of variation which is in fact an aggregate measure: individuals residing in states with higher network coverage are expected to experience a stronger treatment effect. This calls for a triple difference estimator in which I incorporate that coverage as part of the analysis. However, I first wanted to try a standard DiD specification (as there are two; the first one implies comparing eligibles and ineligibles in high coverage states only, and the second one would be comparing eligibles only in high vs low coverage states) and use TD for robustness.